# Limit of SQL 'auto increment' as primary key

Tags: mysql, mariadb, primary-key, auto-increment

I want to create a system of online billboard where everyone can post a topic as my project.

I try to design the database using SQL to store the information of each topic, including the topic's id as primary key.

At first I design the id using integer datatype with auto-increment, as I think it's the simplest way. Then I thought about it and found out that the integer has limit(the number may be high but it is there), so I'm here finding another method.

Now I think of some pseudo-random algorithms, or use the hashing of topic's name but still not clear.

I also find the GUID from research in here, but not sure can it be used.

I wish you suggest me some ways of how to deal with the limit size of integer as primary key, or suggest me any keywords for me to do further research.

Comment: a bigint has limits:  -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) if you expect 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 posts you have another problem....

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MariaDB with MySQL

Comment: You should understand that MariaDB and MySQL are different software products. MariaDB forked from MySQL around 2010, and they are gradually become incompatible with one another.

Comment: Have no fear; 98% of Questions and Answers on this forum apply equally to MySQL and MariaDB.  This Question works the same.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes MySQL/MariaDB, because it uses the terminology "auto-increment" for such columns (as opposed to other databases that use `identity` or `serial`).

If `int` isn't big enough, you can use `bigint`.

Although I might consider it unlikely that you'll exceed the thresholds for `int` (it works for many applications), `bigint` would require great effort on you and your computers part for a long, long time to exceed the maximum value.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 0):

With int, the maximum value supported by SQL Server is 2,147,483,647.

Just for completeness, I will also add that yet another option is to change the data type of the column to bigint (maximum value 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 - this will allow you to insert a million rows per second, for almost 300,000 years in a row).
Or if you fear that you will overflow even that, you can consider using decimal(38,0) - the maximum here is a number consisting of 38 9's (which will allow you to maintain that same pace for a whopping 31,709,791,983,764,586,504,312,531 years).

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis